# "In motion again" vs "into motion again"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Example sentence:

> At last, Mark spoke to Mary, setting the air particles surrounding them in/into motion again.

Should it be in or into and why?

"in motion again" [33K](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1856&bih=931&tbm=bks&ei=o_76Wvu3EoS10ATppIeYDw&q=%22%20in%20motion%20again%22&oq=%22%20in%20motion%20again%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11758.11758.0.11833.1.1.0.0.0.0.61.61.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ML63Rz_WjDs) Google results.

"into motion again" has [9K](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1856&bih=931&tbm=bks&ei=s_76WvmwM4Pc0AT4lL3gBQ&q=%22%20into%20motion%20again%22&oq=%22%20into%20motion%20again%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...28687.28747.0.29151.2.2.0.0.0.0.107.107.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.PSat6oPioRA).

But I'm sttill a little confused.

Comment: There's no particular "Why?" involved. [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+put+in+motion%2Cwas+put+into+motion&year_start=1955&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20put%20in%20motion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20put%20into%20motion%3B%2Cc0) has *put **into** motion* accounting for over a third of all instances over the past 50 years, but if you make the date range a century earlier, it was almost too rare to appear on the chart at all.Use whichever you like, but don't assume either is more "right" or "wrong" than the other.

Comment: Considering how to answer this, a better example might be helpful. I can't get a feeling for the motion, since air particles are always moving the same in a literal sense. In the more likely interpretation, "At last, Mark spoke to Mary, setting the *feelings between* them in/into motion again.", I would use *into* since a change of state clearly has occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more natural to me an **American** English speaker to say into. I know that it has less results but that's how it feels to me given the options. I would say both are valid and would convey what you wish to convey.